# Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type Y?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

The gist of my problem is this:

```
type Bar = [number, number];
interface Foo {
    parameters: Array<Bar>;
}

const okay: Foo = { parameters: [[1, 2], [3, 4]] };

const x = { parameters: [[1, 2], [3, 4]] };
const notOkay: Foo = x; // error!
```

If I declare `okay` inline then it works.

However, if I do the `notOkay` version (which I have to do, because the JSON data is in another file, so I have to import it), then it throws an error.

The only solution seems to be to do `x as Foo`, but that is unfortunate because it bypasses all type-checking.

Is there a solution here which doesn't involve the `as` cast?

Comment: Is it really the code that errored in VS? Are you sure you're not doing something like `const parameters = [[1,2],[3,4]]; const foo: Foo = {parameters: parameters};`? Because obviously, `number[]` is not assignable to `[number, number]`.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure, because the code runs fine. There are no compilation errors with typescript in my terminal. The program runs perfectly at runtime. And the exact same code runs perfectly in the TypeScript playground. It's got to be a VS Code bug, no?

Comment: I'm going to try to make a reproducible git repo one moment.

Comment: The "equivalent" code in the playground is probably using `const json: Foo = { ... }`? It only works because it expects `[number, number][]` and your JSON indeed does have that. However, when you import it as JSON in your workspace, it has type `number[][]`. This is not assignable to type `[number, number]`.

Comment: I made a repro here: https://github.com/treuihreijt/vscode-bug

Comment: You say "copy and paste the exact same code" but that's not literally true, right? If I do that [I get this](https://tsplay.dev/wglxbN) which has errors in it (obviously, since you don't have multiple files there) and doesn't even attempt to assign anything that would make the errors you're talking about.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if anyone's going to install a repo in their local environment.  If you could configure a web IDE project (like codesandbox or stackblitz) that demonstrates it you'll probably have better luck.

Comment: Well you don't have to run the repo yourself you can just look at the code there's only like 10 lines of code or so really

Comment: If I don't run the repo myself how will I demonstrate the issue?  Can you at least share a playground link to "the exact same code" that doesn't have the error?

Comment: From your repo, I confirm what has been said before: `test` is of type `{parameters: number[][]}`, not `{parameters: [number, number][]}`. It will run fine but triggers an error at compile time.

Comment: Well if you don't trust the repo you can just look around the repo to get a feel for what causes the issue and then try to reproduce it similarly in your own environment.

Comment: @Blackhole But isn't `Bar` a tuple type? I don't really understand the issue still.

Comment: typescript isn't that smart yet, it sees [3,4] assumes it is number[ ] instead of [number, number] you need to cast type explicitly. let x: Foo = test as Foo; or let x = test as Foo;

Comment: `Bar` is; the problem come from `test`. Basically, it boils down to that: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANtAvFA2gOzgWwEYQBOANFNvkQLoDcAULQMYD2mAzsFAGZNNRroBGUgCYajFuyh4AhoQBcsBMj5cedIA

Comment: So [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYZxEw) is your issue.  You might want to edit your example code so that it actually demonstrates things.  Others here have a handle on the situation so I'll leave it to one of them to post an answer. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Well I didn't really know the issue at the time but yeah I could edit the original post now sec.